# eigenvector centrality for a directed and weighted graph R

Tags: r, directed-graph, eigenvector, weighted

How can i calculate the **eigenvector** centrality for a directed and weighted graph **g** in **R**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it (I call `g` my network):

```
evcent(g, directed = TRUE, weights=E(g)$weight)$vector
```

However, I do get a warning message when I execute this code. As it was pointed out by [Tamas Nepusz](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2015-11/msg00020.html) it might be better to use Page Rank instead:

```
page.rank(g, directed = TRUE, weights = E(g)$weight)$vector
```